# Cannot initialize std::variant with various lambda expressions

Tags: c++, lambda, future, c++17, variant

I'm playing with `std::variant, lambdas` and `std::future`, and got super weird results when I tried to compose them together. Here are examples:

```cpp
using variant_t = std::variant<
    std::function<std::future<void>(int)>,
    std::function<void(int)>
>;
auto f1 = [](int) { return std::async([] { return 1; }); };
auto f2 = [](int) { return std::async([] {  }); };

variant_t v1(std::move(f1)); // !!! why DOES this one compile when it SHOULDN'T?
auto idx1 = v1.index(); //equals 1. WHY?

variant_t v2(std::move(f2)); // !!! why DOESN'T this one compile when it SHOULD?
```

Here is the compilation error:

> Error C2665   'std::variant<std::function<std::future<void>
>   (int)>,std::function<void (int)>>::variant': none of the 2 overloads
>   could convert all the argument types

OK, lets change `variant`'s items signatures from returning `void` to `int`:

```cpp
using variant_t = std::variant<
    std::function<std::future<int>(int)>,
    std::function<int(int)>
>;

variant_t v1(std::move(f1)); // COMPILES (like it should)
auto idx1 = v1.index(); // equals 0

variant_t v2(std::move(f2)); // DOESN'T compile (like it should)
```

What the hell is going on here? Why is `std::future<void>` so special?

Comment: Note: `std::variant` is a C++17 feature, not C++11.

Comment: Your compile error is from the second example, but your question makes it seem like it's from your first.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`variant`'s converting constructor template employs overload resolution to determine which type the constructed object should have. In particular, this means that if the conversions to those types are equally good, the constructor doesn't work; in your case, it works iff exactly one of the `std::function` specializations is constructible from your argument.

So when is `function<...>` constructible from a given argument? As of  C++14, if the argument is callable with the parameter types and yields a type that is [convertible to the return type](http://eel.is/c++draft/utilities#func.require-2). Note that according to this specification, if the return type is `void`, anything goes (as [any expression can be converted to `void` with `static_cast`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#6)). If you have a `function` returning `void`, the functor you pass in can return anything—that's a feature, not a bug! This is also why `function<void(int)>` is applicable for `f1`. On the other hand,  `future<int>` does not convert to `future<void>`; hence only `function<void(int)>` is viable, and the variant's index is 1.

However, in the second case, the lambda returns `future<void>`, which is convertible to both `future<void>` and `void`. As mentioned above, this causes both `function` specializations to be viable, which is why the `variant` cannot decide which one to construct.

Finally, if you adjust the return type to `int`, this whole `void` conversion issue is avoided, so everything works as expected.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I still cannot imagine how `std::future<int>` can be implicitly convertible to `void` (or `void` to `std::future<int>` - i'm not sure i understood this point)? Does it mean what everithing is convertible to `void`?

Comment: @DmitryKatkevich That is correct, any expression can be converted to `void` via `static_cast`. Otherwise, we could not supply functors to `function` that return something when the `function` yields `void`, which is a desired feature!